# Escape Characters Aren't Working In Debugger (C#)

Tags: c#, escaping

I'm trying to use escape characters to print a double quote. However, my program is throwing an error so I'm trying to debug it. When I add a watch to a string using an escape character it shows that the backslash is being included in the string literal. How do I use escape characters so that the \ doesn't become part of the literal?

[image]

Comment: And where is the code?

Comment: can you show the code that is giving you a problem, not just an image of the results?

Comment: `string fourInch = "4\"";`

Comment: That's just Visual Studio showing the string like that. In the watch window, add `,nq` after the variable name to show the real value: http://i.imgur.com/sZ67gRr.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confused by the debugger's behavior.

VS debugger will show the value with the escape character (Ex: `4\"`) in the `Watch` section and on hovering *but the code will properly use `4"`*

[image: Escape character display in Debugger vs Console]

In the picture above, you can notice it's shown with the escape character by VS but displays correctly in the console.

Comment: This was the answer I needed! Thanks so much

Answer (score -2):

following should work:

```
string fourInch = "4\"";
```

And it does in your example - the string is just shown with escape characters. If you click on the combobox at the end of the value-column and choose "Text" you can see that the correct format is saved...

The problem should be somewhere else in your code...