# Remove double slash from string C#

Tags: c#

I'm currently trying to add this prefix to a TCP IP Message I'm sending

\r\x1c\r

But when the receiver gets it they see

```
\\r\\x1c\\r
```

I tried

```
"\\r\\x1c\\r" + message
@"\r\x1c\r" + message
```

But I keep getting this in front of the message:

```
\\r\\x1c\\r
```

Comment: You are probably viewing this in the debugger because if you print that out to something like the Console or a file it will be what you expect it to be. If you still think it is an error you need to create an [mcve]. You can use https://dotnetfiddle.net/ and post the link in your question.

Comment: Yeah.  I thought that also. But the receiver of the TCP IP message sees the double slashes.

Comment: If you want help you will need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Where are you seeing that?  How?  Through another debugger visualizer?

Comment: I see it in the debugger in the watch tab.  When I actually do a preview of the string the escape characters are not there.

Comment: Are you really sure that's what it is seeing?  Lots of tools mimic the debugger's behavior (showing backslashes as doubles).  That "backslash is the escape character" behavior is common to most C and C-derived languages.  Have you, for instance, checked the string length on the other side?

Comment: That is expected behavior, that is how the watch window works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop visual studio debug putting slash in string containing double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41172620/1260204)

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17918150/2348125

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escape Characters Aren't Working In Debugger (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31410576/escape-characters-arent-working-in-debugger-c)

Comment: So the customer keeps getting the double slashes.  He went on to tell me this \r\x1c\r  ==> 5c 72 5c 78 31 63 5c 72. Does that help any?

Comment: That doesn't look like double slashes to me. Double slashes would be 5c 5c 72 etc. "5c 72" is just "\r". No doubling of the slash.

Comment: @JonSkeet So you are suggesting to just do this "\r\x1c\r" + message ?

Comment: I'm suggesting that your customer is not getting double slashes. I don't know what bytes you *intend* them to receive, as we don't know what sort of protocol you're talking. But you should focus on the bytes that you expect to send, and the bytes you're actually sending. Ignore debugger string representations, which can be highly misleading.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the advice on focusing on what I'm sending.  Yes the debugger is very misleading and sent me down the wrong path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to actually transfer `\r` and `\x1c` as control characters instead. Therefore, you should not escape the backslash.

Send the message like `"\r\x1c\r" + message` or `$"\r\x1c\r{message}"` (without `@`).

When you're using `"\\r"` or `@"\r"`, you're escaping the backslash character and the message will be sent as textual `\r`. When you check the value at the receiver end, using a debugger or watch-window, it will show up as `"\\r"`.

Comment: Yes you are right.  Its like telling them its the beginning of the message. Let me try it out.  Thanks!